# Apparition de l'accent circonflexe ‘^’

Tags: étymologie, histoire, orthographe, diacritiques

On apprend assez vite quand on étudie la langue française que l'accent circonflexe fait souvent suite à une [disparition d'un ancien ‘s’](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Disparition_d.27un_ancien_s). Plusieurs questions alors :

- Est-ce le cas de tous ?
- Comment impose-t-on une telle évolution ? J'imagine en effet qu'il s'agit d'un changement conséquent de prononciation même au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle (l'auxiliaire *estre* deviendrait *être* !)
- Une telle évolution pourrait-elle encore arriver ou l'accentuation est-elle figée ?

Comment: Quêtion intéressante s'il en êt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bonne série de questions !

1) Non. Il y a aussi au moins deux autres types d'accents circonflexes :

- pour différencier des homophones : du/dû, mûr/mur, crû/cru (on utilise aussi l'accent grave pour ce faire : là/la, dès/des) ;
- pour marquer une prononciation particulière : â est toujours vélaire : infâme, grâce ; ê est toujours ouvert ; ô est toujours fermé (sauf si prononcés avec un accent particulier...)

2) En fait, il s'agissait comme toujours de rectifier l'orthographe pour suivre la prononciation effective : les 's' en question ne s'entendaient déjà plus, mais s'écrivaient encore. L'Académie (1740) supprime les 's' devenus muets mais impose le circonflexe pour marquer l'origine étymologique, ce qui permet aussi d'indiquer que les mots modifiés se rapportent aux éventuels autres mots de même origine qui eux n'ont pas perdu leur 's' : fête/festif, etc.

3) L'orthographe en France est à l'heure actuelle ossifiée, toute réforme est quasi-impossible. Ainsi la fameuse tentative de réforme officielle de l'orthographe 1990, qui portait justement entre autres sur les accents circonflexes inutiles (disparaît), a avorté devant une incroyable levée de bouclier et des débats sans fin. À lire les journaux de l'époque, on aurait vraiment cru la Patrie en danger. Cela a finalement abouti à une liste de "tolérances orthographiques" pour les écrits dont l'administration a à connaître : ainsi on doit pouvoir écrire "disparait" dans une copie de baccalauréat sans subir les foudres du correcteur.

Depuis, le développement du texte informatisé et des correcteurs orthographiques en ligne (basés en général sur l'orthographe classique) assurent que toute réforme, voire toute déviation, sont découragés.

Comment: Pour 3) je n'y crois vraiment pas une seconde. La prononciation évoluera de toute façon toujours et l'orthographe finira bien par évoluer avec si elle n'évolue pas d'elle même.

Comment: @Evpok, j'aimerais bien être d'accord avec toi... mais la perspective d'une réforme orthographique profonde comme en ont connu d'autres langues me semble éloignée.

Comment: De fait, la partie de la réforme de 1990 concernant les accents circonflexes entérine plutôt des formes « fautives » [Esprit prescriptiviste, sors de ce corps !] qui existaient concurremment avec les formes portant l'accent circonflexe. Elles ont donc été suivies, ou plutôt précédées, par l'usage. (On pourrait en dire autant de l'orthographe des nombres, où l'utilisation du trait d'union était pour le moins déjà flottante). Ce qui n'a vraiment pas pris, ce sont les réformes orthographiques ponctuelles indépendantes de l'usage (ognon, nénufar, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

L'article de Wikipédia que tu signales donne déjà un début de réponse pour ton second point

> Le /s/ devant une consonne s'est amuï au XIe siècle, aux alentours de 1066, entraînant un allongement compensatoire (et une fermeture permanente de la voyelle /o/), lequel s'est effacé après le XVIIIe siècle

Le changement phonétique n'a pas été imposé par la graphie, c'est l'inverse qui s'est produit. Les changements d'orthographes prennent acte du fait que le `/s/` a disparu. La suite de l'article montre d'ailleurs que c'est loin d'avoir été instantané. Quand au caractère conséquent du changement de prononciation, comme il s'est fait graduellement il n'a sans doute pas été perçu par la majorité des locuteurs.

Pour ton premier point

> Parfois, l'accent circonflexe n'a pas d'origine précise. Il peut, par exemple, être ajouté à un mot pour le rendre plus prestigieux : c'est le cas dans trône, prône ou suprême. D'autre part, à la première personne du pluriel du passé simple de l'indicatif, l'accent circonflexe n'a été ajouté que par analogie avec celui, motivé, de la deuxième personne du pluriel.

Quant à ton dernier point, la réponse est sans doute *oui*, peu de choses sont immuables en linguistique, par exemple des mots courants comme *château* ou *gâteau* sont souvent fautivement écrit sans et le perdront sûrement à l'avenir. L'Académie a aussi essayé de simplifier

> Conscients des grandes difficultés que représente l'emploi de l'accent circonflexe et du nombre d'incohérences dans son emploi, les experts représentant les instances francophones compétentes chargées de mettre au point des simplifications de l'orthographe officielle du français ont proposé en 1990 des rectifications orthographiques, publiées au Journal officiel de la République française6. Le circonflexe devient optionnel sur i et u sauf dans les cas où cela entraîne une ambiguïté (il croît ─ verbe croître ─ garde son circonflexe pour se différencier d'il croit ─ verbe croire).

(Toujours du même article).

Comment: l'article wikipedia est en effet très complet sur ce point mais il est bien marqué comme "manquant de sources" c'est pourquoi j'ai préféré sollicité l'expertise de ce stackexchange. (même si ces experts francophiles peuvent être les mêmes écrivant l'article wikipedia ;)

Comment: [La bibliographie de l'article sur wp:en](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French#Bibliography) est assez complète, je n'ai pas les ouvrages en question sous la main mais je ne doute pas que les wikipédiens s'en sont servi.

Answer (score 7):

- **Tous les usages de l'accent circonflexe ne proviennent pas de la disparition d'une lettre *s*.** Par exemple, [*âge*](http://francois.gannaz.free.fr/Littre/xmlittre.php?requete=%C2GE) a remplacé *aage* au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle.
- **Une telle évolution est encore possible**: la réforme de l'orthographe de 1990 prône la [supression de l'accent circonflexe sur les voyelles *u* et *i*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#D.C3.A9tail), sauf en cas d'homonymie dans les formes du passé simple et du subjonctif.
- Sur la nature des évolutions et de son introduction en français, l'article [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_circonflexe_en_fran%C3%A7ais) sur la question est assez clair.